# PHP - Parsing results are not consistent

Tags: php, parsing

Parsing a string value to a float value is not consistent in my PHP project. Altough I'm not changing my code and the values to parse are always the same I sometimes get a result with a comma and sometimes with a point.

The incoming value is for example: 35,59
Before parsing this value I first replace the comma by a point.

```
$value = '35,59';
$value = (float)str_replace(',', '.', $value);
var_dump($value);
```

When I now use this value in my insert query, this sometimes results in a bug because a comma is used.
This is all a bit weird to me, has anyone experienced this before? How can I prevent this from happening?

**Edit:**
I indeed forgot my quotes in this example, but I did use quotes in my code

Comment: change $value = 35,59; to $value = "35,59";

Comment: The problem is that `$value` is not a string in the first line...

Comment: replace all dots for nothing and after replace all comas for dot

Comment: *Assuming* the value in your example is actually quoted, may you be stumbling over the fact that PHP formats floats according to locale when converting them to a string? I.e. `echo $float` prints different results depending on the set locale.

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = 35,59;
```

The problem is that the parser cannot recognize "," as a decimal delimiter. Your locale may define numbers this way but programmatically you must use periods or declare the value as a string.

```
$value = "35,59";
// or
$value = 35.59;
```

If you get `35,59`, that must be hard-coded since any data-source returning this value is automatically treated as a string.

See https://www.php.net/numberformatter.parse for information on how to cast the formatted string correctly.

I.e

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'sv_SE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$value = "35,59";
echo $fmt->parse($value); // 35.59
```

**Edit**
Also your `str_replace` will fail for X number of locales since some usually use "," as a thousand separator.